# how to retrieve static file's contents in django view?

Tags: django, static

I have html files and I want to give the contents of the file to user from a django view.

Basically these files are data files whose internal sturcture is html.

** Edit **

*So you want to render them (display them in the browser), or send them for download? Are they templates, or files the users have uploaded?*

A: Clients will use the html(and other data as well) and replace certain part of the page with it. (I think how I'll use it is not that important though. We can treat html contents as a data)

*Will you know the names of the files in question when you write the software, or will you only know their names at runtime?*

A: I currently have a table which has the filepath as a field. ie. The filepath can be changed at runtime

Comment: So you want to _render_ them (display them in the browser), or send them for download? Are they templates, or files the users have uploaded?

Comment: Will you know the names of the files in question when you write the software, or will you only know their names at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to leverage the staticfiles storage system.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

file_handle = staticfiles_storage.open(your_filename)
contents = file_handle.read()
```

the filename (`your_filename` above) should be the relative path to the static file (not including the STATIC_URL (`/static/[this part]`)

#### Edit: Finder vs Storage

If you want to find static files stored in app directories (or other configured static finders), you need to use a finder, not the storage to retrieve the file contents.  Here's how to do that:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.finders import find
file_path = "relative/path/to/file.extension"
abs_path = find(file_path)
file(abs_path).read()
```

Comment: was hard to find this info. How did you get this info? by looking at doc? or looking at source?

Comment: I had a related but distinct use case.  I just looked up the static template tag source to see how that was resolving the files and drilled through the static files app. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py

Comment: ah ok. thanks for the tip. That makes sense.  I'll have to look for the code where it lookups app/static/ folder (not the static_dir/app/static). it would be more convenient when developing.

Comment: For app directory lookups, you need a staticfiles *finder*, not a *storage*.  Storages are where files are processed and converted to (including remote locations like S3, FTP, etc).  Finders scour your configured apps and filesystem locations configured by your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting.  I updated the answer with a code sample for this case.

Comment: May I ask what's the difference between them? should I use the first option in production?

Comment: If you want the contents of a file, I'd use a `finder` since the file will be local (storage could be on a remote node like S3).  If you want a url to the file, use `storage`.

Comment: **Big caveat** on that last advise, you have to include your static assets in your source distribution on each app server for that to work.  If you use a different deployment method (such as running `collectstatic` from a dedicated machine) this can lead to missing files.

Comment: I gist'd a function to handle opening a static file regardless of whether it's been collected: https://gist.github.com/jdunck/0fd1dbc720b352b04c8e